# Change return value of other attribute than in object patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I have the following unittest.

```py
class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers: Dict[str, str] = {}

    def add(self, name: str, number: str) -> None:
        self.numbers[name] = number

    def lookup(self, name: str) -> str:
        return self.numbers[name]


class Mobile:
    def __init__(self, phonebook: PhoneBook):
        self.phonebook = phonebook

    def call(self, name: str) -> None:
        number = self.phonebook.lookup(name)
        logging.info(f"Calling {name} on number: {number}")


@mock.patch.object(PhoneBook, "add")
def test_mobile_call(mock_phonebook: PhoneBook):
    # Arrange
    mock_phonebook.lookup.return_value = "123"
    mobile = Mobile(mock_phonebook)
    # Act
    mobile.call("Nick")
    # Assert
    mock_phonebook.lookup.assert_called_with("Nick")
```

With the patch annotation I expect to patch the `add` function/method of the PhoneBook. But as you can see I am actually able to change the return value of the `lookup` method and assert it was called with a specific value.

- I am not sure if this is actually the expected result?
- Why do I give it the "add" parameter in the annotation if that attribute of the `PhoneBook` is not even patched/used? Like, why is there no further checking on this? If I put an empty string, or an attribute that is not part of the `PhoneBook` it throws an error.
- Am I using the patch annotation for the wrong purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that you are not actually calling the patched function (`Phonebook.add`). What you get from that patch is a `MagickMock` object that patches the function, but other than that is just a generic mock.

What are are doing is equivalent to:

```py
def test_mobile_call():
    # Arrange
    mock_phonebook = MagicMock()
    mock_phonebook.lookup.return_value = "123"
    mobile = Mobile(mock_phonebook)
    # Act
    mobile.call("Nick")
    # Assert
    mock_phonebook.lookup.assert_called_with("Nick")
```

In short, you don't need to patch anything in this case, because the object you want to mock is passed as an argument to the tested function.